# How to edit .LAN Files with delphi 7

Tags: delphi

I want to edit some .LAN files with Delphi 7. I can open them using notepad. My question is can i do the same using Delphi also? Or is there some in-built functions like TIniFile,TRegistry etc. which has inbuilt functions?

Ideas would be appreciated. 
Thanks

Comment: Main idea: do not identify file format by its extension. FYI, well known content for `.lan` extension is raster data of the one well known GIS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can open a .LAN file in Notepad (and the content makes sense), it means that a .LAN file is just a plain-text file. And, of course, plain-text files can be easily opened in Delphi. Just open it the way you would open a 'normal' .TXT file (using `TStringList`, for instance). It doesn't matter that the extension is different, as long as it is a plain-text file.

Now, I have no idea what a .LAN file contains. It most definitely is not a common file format, so I am pretty sure that the RTL/VCL has no parser for it.

However, if a .LAN file has the structure of an .INI file, then -- of course -- you can treat it like an .INI file and use the `TIniFile` (or the `TMemIniFile`).

One word of caution, however. You are using an old version of Delphi. Delphi 7 doesn't support Unicode in its VCL, so if the .LAN files are Unicode, then you need to apply some trix when reading and writing it.

(If it is UTF-8 without a BOM, you might lose special characters, but that is it. If there is a BOM, just remove it. If the file is using two bytes per character, it will look strange to you e v e n   i f   i t   d o e s n ' t   c o n t a i n   a n y   s p e c i a l   c h a r a c t e r s. In any case, some trix will do it for you.)

## ☂

Comment: trix? blah blah blah 15 characters in length blah blahj

Comment: @David: Not too bad, though: UTF8Encode, UTF8Decode, for instance.

Comment: Thanks Anderas. You have been a life saver today. You saved me from line of fire in work.

Comment: daemon_x just gave an example of a character you cannot use without Unicode, namely `U+2602: UMBRELLA`.